# I am cloning a repository from Bitbucket but getting these errors while installing dependencies

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

this project is built in nodeJS and using Mysql as backend when i install the dependencies this giving me errors
i have nodejs 16.15.1 installed in my pc and
and package.json include mysql version 2.15.0,

what i done here, i cloned this project from bitbucket using HTTPS
and tried to install the dependencies using `npm install` after that it returning a huge list of errors

here is the screenshot of that image
[here is the pack.json fle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPd3q.png)

[error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huezh.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would recommend you read through [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on creating quality question posts! Your post right now isn't very helpful. For example, there is a lot of information missing information. What repository is this? How are you cloning and building the project (i.e. the exact steps, etc.)? What versions of NodeJS and MySQL are you using? There are a lot of missing details here, which prevent the community from helping you.

Comment: ok Ive edit as much as i can

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies you are using are outdated or may be shifted to another version, with different names.

Apply these solution:

1. Remember the name of dependencies and then remove it from package.json and then install it with their name no need to specify their version number.
2. Some of dependencies shifted to other name so search their updated name then install it with their updated name

Comment: yes , I've updated the node-gyp into latest and using the latest node version now its fine

Comment: @YogeshKumar Can you accept a correct answer then, if your question has been solved?

Answer (score -1):

Hi Yogesh Kumar can you provide a screen shot of error. but may be your error solve with this:

When you clone a repository, you create a copy of your Bitbucket repository on your local system. Cloning also connects the remote and local repositories so that you can start pushing and pulling changes between both places.
Clone a Git repository

You can use the terminal, SourceTree, or any other client you'd like to clone your Git repository. These instructions show you how to clone your repository using Git from the terminal.

```
In the repository, select the Clone button.

Copy the clone command.

From a terminal window, change into the local directory where you want to clone your repository.

$ cd <path_to_directory>               

Paste the command you copied from Bitbucket, for example:

$ git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/documentation-tests.git
```

If the clone was successful, a new sub-directory appears on your local drive with the same name as the repository that you cloned.

Comment: I already cloned this one but when i install the dependencies using npm install it giving me error huge list of error and yes i uploaded the ss of the error its you can click the imgur link

Comment: oh i see your image , if you provide me a package.json file image that would be very help full for me

Comment: now check the pack.json file ive uploaded the ss